# Processing form on same page vs separate page

Tags: php

What are the advantages/disadvantages of processing forms on the same page vs on a separate page? I'm using PHP to handle my forms. Any input is appreciated.

Comment: [(PHP) Is handling a form submission on the same page more/less/equally good as handling on a separate page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354644/php-is-handling-a-form-submission-on-the-same-page-more-less-equally-good-as-h?rq=1)

Comment: Generally i find processing on separate pages easier to debug as you can see the processing and the form display logic easier if they are not mangled together.

Comment: But i have to flag the question for removal as it is asking for opinions and there is no correct way to answer it.

Comment: same page lets you easily reload with error messages and the previous filled in contents